# Add Number of days and time on a datetime field

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following sheet:

```
  | A               | B          | C
1 | 23/2/2020 12:00 | 5          | 2:00
2 | 12/4/2020 13:00 | 2          | 2:0
```

And I want to calculate how many days after and how many hours after the date will be. So as an example the `23/2/2020 12:00`will be `28/02/2020 14:00`.

Just by doing `=A1+C1` I get `23/2/2020 12:00` (I add the hours) but how I will increase the datetime by days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=A1+B1+C1` In your example. If the column values are formatted as the picture below shows.

[image: Example]